Migrate the result of mongodb.runCommand in MongoDB driver 3 to 5
I am trying to migrate an application that uses mongodb driver 3.0 to driver-synch 5.1 in java 17. This application has a functionality that receives a json with the format:
{"aggregate": "Vuce", "pipeline": [{"$match": {"Form": {"$eq": 109}}}, {"$project": {"Col1": "$DocInst", "Col2": "AAAAAAAAAAAA"}}], "cursor": {}}

Executes it as "mongodb.runCommand(query)" and returns the result of, in this example, the aggregation (I would much prefer not changing the syntax of the query document, since they have several hundreds, but I am open to suggestions).
However, I have different documents in the different versions and I, ultimately, can't access the result of the command in the newer documents.
In the previous version, the result of the aggregation had a List< Document > in the field "result", with all the documents that fit the criteria. This changed , now the command returns a generic document with the following format:
{cursor: Document{{firstBatch: [Document{{_id: 11376, Col2: AAAAAAAAAAAA}}, Document{{_id: 11568, Col2: AAAAAAAAAAAA}}, ...], id: 7067558295212936488, ns: Vuce.Vuce}}, ok: 1.0}}

The resulting document indicates that the query was resolved, and includes a list with the partial result, and information about the MongoCursor. According to the documentation, the idea is to use "getMore" to iterate on the collection. However, since it is a Document, all the contained information are plain elements, there is no way (as far as I have seen) to get to the MongoCursor object in order to continue iterating.
My maven dependencies look like this:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

My question is: How can I iterate on this new version of runCommand? Can I get an iterator or a cursor from that result? Is there another way to execute that "query" that returns an iterator?
Thank you

You would do subsequent mongodb.runCommand({ getMore: 7067558295212936488, collection: "Vuce"}), since getMore is a command which takes the cursor id (7067558295212936488 in your example, returned by the database in the initial response) as input. It's unclear why you're doing such "low level" coding though, the driver should transparently handle this (eg getMores) for you - eg 'Basic Aggregation Example' in the docs


Is there another way to execute that "query" that returns an iterator?

Yes, you can try this approach. Here is an example.
Your json:
{"aggregate": "Vuce", "pipeline": [{"$match": {"Form": {"$eq": 109}}}, {"$project": {"Col1": "$DocInst", "Col2": "AAAAAAAAAAAA"}}], "cursor": {}}

I have a simplified version of your json, which uses a collection test and a simple pipeline. You extract the collection name and the aggregation pipeline and work with it.
String s = """
           { "aggregate": "test", "pipeline": [{"$match": {"a": {"$eq": 1}}}], "cursor": {}}
           """;
Bson json = new JsonObject(s);
BsonDocument bsonDoc = json.toBsonDocument();
List<BsonDocument> bsonPipe = bsonDoc.getArray("pipeline")
                    .stream()
                    .map(BsonValue::asDocument)
                    .toList();
String colName = bsonDoc.getString("aggregate").getValue();

// Assuming you have a MongoClient instance and a database called "test"

AggregateIterable<Document> aggResult = mongoClient.getDatabase("test")
                    .getCollection(colName)
                    .aggregate(bsonPipe);
List<Document> resultDocs = new ArrayList<>();
aggResult.into(resultDocs);
System.out.println(resultDocs);

The server version 4.4 and Java version 17. I was using this Java driver dependency in my pom.xml:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
  <version>4.11.1</version>
</dependency>

